# how to remove the android system gallery thumbnails

Tags: android, android-gallery

Here is my code:

```
File storageFile = new File("/mnt/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/IMG_123456789.jpg");

if(storageFile.exists()) {
    //copy the file to another folder
    MyCopyFoo(storageFile);

    if(storageFile.delete()) {
        Log.d("Debug", "Success!");//have shown
        //refresh sth 
    }
}
```

After operation, I checked the system gallery, and there is still a thumbnail in it.
When I restarted the system, it was gone.
I know there is some other way to handle this- the "setting"=>clear sth

What if I wanna deal with it in the code above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`MediaScannerConnection`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html) to notify the system of modified media files and to regenerate their metadata and thumbnails.

Mediascanner runs as part of the boot sequence so that's why a reboot also fixes the issue.